# mod_rewrite - passing a variable directly from home url not working

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I already created a rule that allows users to pass a variable like this: **somepage.com/database/12345** which internally changes it to **somepage.com/database/?db_index=12345** and it works fine. The code looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^database/([0-9]+)/?$ /database/?db_index=$1
```

Now I need to do exactly the same but without the need to pass "database/" before the variable. So the users can pass the variable like this: **somepage.com/12345**. It has to be an additional option, not a replacement for the previous one. I tried to do this like that:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /database/?db_index=$1 [L]
```

but I just can't get this to work and I have no idea why. The additional code above is inserted directly before the previous working rule.

I'll be really happy for any help and explanation why my method doesn't work.

UPDATE: the whole .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Block the include-only files.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]

# direct url rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /database/?db_index=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^database/([0-9]+)/?$ /database/?db_index=$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Strange, this should work. What is the error you get?

Comment: Yeap, strugling to see a problem with that

Comment: I get #404 so the template page that displays the results isn't even loading. I'm pasting the whole content of the .htaccess file - maybe there is a problem somewhere else in it?

Comment: I updated the original question above with the full .htaccess code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours looks fine to me, but try: `RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/?$ /database/?db_index=$1 [R=301]`

Comment: It works but displays the URL with var name (as somesite.com/database?db_index=123) so I slightly modified that to: **RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/?$ /database/$1 [R=301]** - now it works like a charm, thanks a lot!  Do you have any idea why the previous solution didn't work at all?

Comment: @NoviQ - two possible reasons: (1) `^/?` in pattern; or (2) issue(s) with `[L]` in rule. You can log rewrite stuff to debug it and find the reason if you want to, but as you found an alternative solution, you don't have to dig it :) Good luck!